# Spring boot 3 org.hibernate.query.SemanticException when updating an enum data type

Tags: spring-boot, enums, spring-data-jpa

With the following code,

Entity:

```
@Column
@Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
private MyStatusEnum status;
```

```
public enum MyStatusEnum {
  ENABLED,
  DISABLED
}
```

Repository method:

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE MyEntityClass e SET e.status = 'ENABLED'")
int setEnabledStatus();
```

When trying to start the application i got the following exception:

`... Caused by: org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: The assignment exppression type [java.lang.String] did not match the assignment path type [...MyStatusEnum] for the path [e.status] [UPDATE MyEntityClass e SET e.status = 'ENABLED']`

Has anyone experienced the same issue?
I'm using spring boot 3.0.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the enum value not a string:

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE MyEntityClass e SET e.status = MyStatusEnum.ENABLED")
int setEnabledStatus();
```

because JPA works with Objects